# Fatal error: Class Filesystemiterator not found

Tags: php

I'm getting that error when trying to use this code

```
<?php
$fi = new FilesystemIterator("image/Images", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$count = iterator_count($fi);
if ($count-2<0){
$i = 0;
}
else{
$i = $count -2;
}
echo $i;
?>
```

Is there an alternative to what I have written? I think it might be something to do with my version of php on my webhost... I don't want to change the version though, so a work around would be helpful.

Comment: Counting images. Part of larger code. Only issue is with the FilesystemIterator.

Comment: FileSystemIterator requires PHP >= 5.3.0 If you're running a lower version than that, then you're unsupported and should be upgrading, whether you want to or not.... if your web hosting doesn't provide a higher version than that, then you should be moving to a different web hosting provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) like this:

```
$fi = glob("image/Images/*.*");
$count = count($fi);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Baker mentioned on comment -

**FileSystemIterator requires PHP >= 5.3.0**

and my PHP version is lower than 5.3.0 , I upgraded that fixed my problem.

Either you could check `phpversion` or `class_exists` before calling `FileSystemIterator`